# Rails JSX file not working

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, reactjs

I'm new to ruby-on-rails, can someone tell where i am supposed to put the JSX file so that it renders the content into the DOM?

i have 2 separate views, one for 'home' and another for 'details'. in the 'views' directory in rails, there is a separate folder for the different views, but they all sit inside the same javascript directory.

if i call the files home.js.jsx and details.js.jsx... rails won't do any thing for react.

if i call them home-templates.js.jsx and details-templates.js.jsx, rails will only render the jsx for details.

I then put my code at the bottom of 'html.html.erb' insides a `<script type='text/jsx'>` tag, but still not working.

Where am i going wrong?

Comment: If you run the installation script provided by `react-rails`, ( `rails g react:install`) you'll notice it creates a components folder under assets/javascripts for your react components. This is for organizational purposes but anywhere in assets/javascripts should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

JSX files can't be interpreted natively by browsers. You'd have to compile them to plain JavaScript before.

A popular choice is to use [Grunt](http://gruntjs.com/) together with [Babel](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/jsx/). There is also the [React-Rails](https://github.com/reactjs/react-rails) gem, which may offer a better integration in the Rails asset pipeline

Comment: i am using the React-Rails gem.